# how to find first row first anchor tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find  first row first anchor tag in jquery ?

[image]

I have `4` rows .I want to get `first row` anchor tag. I tried like this

https://jsbin.com/woxatuxoju/edit?html,js,output

```
$(()=>{

 console.log( $('a[title=" Nominal"]')[0])

 $('a[title=" Nominal"]')[0].css({'background-color':'red'})
})
```

but not able to find correct element.

Comment: can you please share the complete html

Comment: in a link it is present

Comment: can you share it here? jsbin dont work in my network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('a[title=" Nominal"]')[0]` returns the DOM object of element and not the jquery object. Due to this `.css ()` method is not applying the changes.

You should use `.eq()` selector to get jquery object of element by its index:

```
 $('a[title=" Nominal"]:eq(0)').css({'background-color':'red'});
```

Using Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsbin.com/xohelufeci/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: correct asnswer. can we use `pure javascript` using `queryselector`  ??

Comment: is it possible ??